# Is a parallel 4 link safe compared to a triangulated 4 link?

Tags: suspension, hotrod, rear-end

After researching the topic the closest article I've ever been able to find was written by Ridetech: "[What’s the difference between a triangulated 4 link and a parallel 4 link?](http://www.ridetech.com/info/air4link-tech/)".  However, a concern with running the Parallel 4 link wouldn't it be bad on the truck frame during vehicle articulation?  Most Parallel 4-link kits I've researched use Urethane bushings but wouldn't it ride like a covered wagon, too?

Comment: Your bags are going to take up most of the harshness in the ride. I don't think I'd worry too much about Urethane bushings. The bushings will help in other areas like for traction and stopping due to not allowing the suspension to load up during those events.

Comment: link dead. some "form error" code on their page.

Answer (score 0):

How much 'articulation' do you need?  Is this a rock crawler?  Then do a double triangulated suspension and be done with it.  If this is a street truck with high spring rates, slammed etc.  You are not going to be leaning the truck far enough.

If you are building a race car, either triangulated (see NASCAR) or torque arm (see 1987-2002 Camaro/Firebird - or Griggs racing mustang).
The point being, you don't want any binding at all (stiction or otherwise) in your suspension.  Make the springs, shocks and swaybars do their jobs.  Suspension pieces just guide the axle.  You'll typically need solid bushings (rod ends or johnny joints).